# UI blocked while NSFetchedResultsController loading data

Tags: iphone, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I managed UITableView via NSFetchedResultsController, but all UI blocked(I can do nothing such as tap, scroll...) while NSFetchedResultsController loading data. Is there any solution to resolve this? Thanks!!!

Comment: May be you can reduce the batch size

Comment: Now the batch size is 20，Is that high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that is important to remember when making your application user friendly is:

> If you have any intensive, non-`UI` related computations on the ***Main
>   Thread***, you are doing something wrong!

Making the ***Main Thread*** `UI` only will make sure that the `UI` will never freeze, or as you describe it, get "blocked". Therefore, your `NSFetchedResultsController` should be on another thread, to ensure that this doesn't happen.

`NSOperation`'s is definitely the way to go for the problem you are describing. [Here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/03/04/iphone-coding-turbo-charging-your-apps-with-nsoperation/) is a tutorial and sample code which will explain a similar scenario, and how to fix it up.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: It seems cause the other problems.

Comment: I download data from internet(if needed) and then load data from core data to UITableView

Comment: Great! So now, all you have to do is put all of that functionality into a method, and wrap that method in an `NSOperation`, and then call `reloadData` when that is complete, and your `UI` won't lock up!

Comment: I used ASIHTTPRequest for http request, and save data to core data in it's setCompletionBlock, It wrapped by NSOperation...